# Eikonal equation with zero right-hand side

Tags: partial-differential-equations, steady-state

I have the eikonal equation:

$$\left|\frac{du}{dx}(x)\right| = 0, \, x\in \Omega, \quad u(x) = f(x), \, x\in \Gamma.$$

Does the above have the same solution as:

$$\frac{du}{dx}(x) = 0, \, x\in \Omega, \quad u(x) = f(x), \, x\in \Gamma$$

My intuition is that if I look at the time evolution the two seem to be different, in the sense that $|u_x|=u_t$ would have fronts propagating in either direction from the boundary, while $u_x=u_t$ (or $-u_x=u_t$) would propagate those only in one direction. Is this a correct interpretation. But if the above is the case wouldn't the steady states (i.e. for $T\rightarrow\infty$) differ?

I have done some numerical simulations and wanted to make sure that the solutions I get are not artifacts of my discretisation but arise from the model. I prescribe Dirichlet data pointwise $u(x_i) = f(x_i)$, and I am able to recover piecewise constant interpolation as the solution in all cases. Taking different time evolutions results in different solutions for the steady state ($T\rightarrow \infty$):

$$u_t=u_x \implies u(x)=f(x_i), \, x\in [x_i, x_{i+1})$$
$$u_t=-u_x \implies u(x)=f(x_i), \, x\in (x_{i-1}, x_i]$$
$$u_t=|u_x| \implies u(x)=f(x_i), \, x\in \left(\frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}{2}, \frac{x_{i}+x_{i+1}}{2}\right)$$

To me this implies that the three equations $u_t = \pm u_x$ and $u_t = |u_x|$ are in fact different and the difference arises in what happens at the boundaries, which then propagates to form the steady state.

The steady states have discontinuities so to me it looks like the first is taking a right derivative at the boundaries, the second a left derivative, and the third some combination of the two.

Comment: Could you please clarify whats $\Omega$ where you prescribe the dirichlet boundary conditions?

Comment: @maxmilgram $\Omega$ is the solution domain, $\Gamma$ is where I prescribe the Dirichlet conditions. The Dirichlet conditions in my case are prescribed over $\Gamma = \{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$. If the resulting Dirac deltas are too bothersome it's fine to relax this to $\Gamma = \bigcup_i [x_i-\Delta, x_i+\Delta]$. A case with the Dirac delta constraints is discussed for even order PDEs in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01601941 Essentially one gets interpolating splines of odd degree for the solution. The above problem that I have is the odd order PDE counterpart.

Comment: I am still confused: Is $\Omega$ the domain including the time, that means $\Omega=\Gamma\times\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @maxmilgram $\Omega$ is an open set, and the boundary is where Dirichlet data is prescribed: $\partial\Omega=\Gamma$. There's no time in the initial problem: $|u_x| = 0$. However to get the stready state one can extend the problem to a time evolution one $|u_x|=u_t$ and by looking for the solution at $T\rightarrow\infty$ one recovers the steady state. If you stop early you just get a solution with wavefronts emanating from $\Gamma$ that have not collided yet. The steady state is the same as the solution for time $T$ where the fronts have collided. You get a Voronoi decomposition basically.

Comment: I understand that, what throws me off is that you have only one spacedimension. So i assume that $\Omega$ is an intervall and $\Gamma$ are two points. So why is $\Gamma=\{x_1,...x_n\}$?

Comment: @maxmilgram $\Omega$ can be several intervals if I have more than 2 points: $\Omega = \bigcup_i (x_i, x_{i+1})$. But for simplicity you can consider that there are only 2 points and $\Omega$ is 1 interval. The solutions in the various intervals are not coupled after all. Then the three solutions are $u(x)=f(x_0), u(x_1) = f(x_1)$, or $u(x)=f(x_1), u(x_0) = f(x_0)$, or $u([x_0,0.5x_0+0.5x_1)) = f(x_0), u((0.5x_0+0.5x_1,x_1])=f(x_1)$. The last one resulting from the eikonal equation, the first from $u_x$ and right derivative at BC, the second from $-u_x$ and left derivative at BC.